# Определить, что страница прокручена вверх Javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код

```
let lastScrollTop = 0
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    let scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document
      .documentElement.scrollTop;
    
    if (scrollTop < lastScrollTop) {
      console.log('top')
    }
    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
  });
```

Собственно он прекрасно работает, но как сделать так, что бы console.log срабатывал только тогда, когда страница прокручена вверх на, скажем, 200 пикселей, а не сразу. Быть может есть аналогичные решения.

Comment: Почитай [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/onscroll)

Comment: На пальцах - Надо засечь начальную точку замера и во время скролла сравнивать разницу, если условие выполняется, делать желаемое